# Bind more than one domain via ldap and php

Tags: php, ldap

Currently I have a project that authenticates via ldap to modify contact attribute, but only in a single domain, I'm trying to add an implementation so I can identify which domain the user wants to authenticate after informing on a form, example:
domain\user.

Here's how my code treats only one domain.

```
index.php

<?php

set_time_limit(30);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);


/*
* Function Find user: Procura o usuario no LDAP
*/

$ldap_server = "iphost";
$ldap_binddn = "CN=LDAP Change Info,CN=Users,DC=DOMAIN,DC=com,DC=br";
$ldap_bindpw = "passwordhere";
$ldap_search_dn = "DC=domain,DC=com,DC=br";



function erro($mensagem, $goto_page = "") {

        if ($mensagem == "") {
                $_SESSION['last_error'] = "";
                return;
        }else{
                $_SESSION['last_error'] = $mensagem;
        }

        if ($goto_page == "") {
                $goto_page = "error.php";
        }
        include("_include/$goto_page");
        die();
}

function modify_user_attribute($userdn, $attributes) {

        global $ldap_server;
        global $ldap_binddn;
        global $ldap_bindpw;
        global $ldap_search_dn;

        /*
        *
        * Conexão no servidor LDAP.
        */
        #TODO: Fazer conectar em outro servidor caso o primeiro de erro.
        $ldap = ldap_connect($ldap_server) or die("LDAP Server connect error.");
        ldap_set_option($ldap, LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS, 0);
        ldap_set_option($ldap, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);

        $ret = false;

        if ($ldap) {
                $ldapbind = ldap_bind($ldap, $ldap_binddn, $ldap_bindpw);
                if ($ldapbind) {
                        $ret = ldap_modify($ldap, $userdn, $attributes);
                        ldap_close($ldap);
                }
        }
        return $ret;
}

function check_value($value, $name) {

        if ($value == null) {
                erro("Atributo $name não pode ser nulo", "modify.php");
        }

        if ($value == "") {
                erro("Atributo $name não pode ser vazio", "modify.php");
        }

        if (strlen($value) > 20) {
                erro("Atributo $name não pode conter mais do que 20 caracteres.", "modify.php");
        }
}

function find_and_auth_user($login, $senha) {

        global $ldap_server;
        global $ldap_binddn;
        global $ldap_bindpw;
        global $ldap_search_dn;

        $ldap_user_to_find = "";
        $ldap_user_pass = "";
        $ldap_user_dn = "";
        /*
        *
        * Conexão no servidor LDAP.
        */
        #TODO: Fazer conectar em outro servidor caso o primeiro de erro.
        $ldap = ldap_connect($ldap_server) or die("LDAP Server connect error.");
        ldap_set_option($ldap, LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS, 0);
        ldap_set_option($ldap, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);

        if (!$ldap) {
                //Redirecionar o usuário para uma tela de erro de sistema.
        }

        # Find
        $ldapbind = ldap_bind($ldap, $ldap_binddn, $ldap_bindpw);
        if ($ldapbind) {
                $ldap_search_filter = "(sAMAccountName=$login)";

                $result = ldap_search($ldap, $ldap_search_dn, $ldap_search_filter) or erro("Erro de sistema");

                $data = ldap_get_entries($ldap, $result);
                if ($data["count"] == 1) {
                        $ldap_user_dn = $data[0]["dn"];
#                       print "Encontrado usuário: " . $ldap_user_dn . "\n";


                        $ldapbind2 = ldap_bind($ldap, $ldap_user_dn, $senha);
                        if ($ldapbind2) {

                                $result = ldap_search($ldap, $ldap_user_dn, $ldap_search_filter) or erro("Erro de sistema");
                                $data = ldap_get_entries($ldap, $result);


                                /*
                                * Salva na sessão os dados encontrados.
                                */
                                $_SESSION['dn'] = $ldap_user_dn;
                                $_SESSION['telephonenumber'] = $data[0]["telephonenumber"][0];
                                $_SESSION['ipphone'] = $data[0]["ipphone"][0];
                                $_SESSION['last_error'] = "";

                                return true;

                        }else{
                                #Redireciona o usuário para página de erro de login e senha.
                                erro("Usuário ou senha incorreta.", "login.php");
                        }
                }else{
                        erro("Usuário ou senha incorreta.", "login.php");
                }
        }

        ldap_close($ldap);
}


#
#
# SINGLE PAGE APP
#
#
#


if (session_id() == "") {

        session_start();

        //GET = Formulario de LOGIN
        if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'GET') {
                $_SESSION['last_error'] = "";
                include("_include/login.php");
                return;
        }

        if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {

                //POST do formulario de LOGIN
                if (isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password'])) {
                        if (find_and_auth_user($_POST['username'], $_POST['password'])){
                                include("_include/modify.php");
                        }
                        return;
                }


                //POST do formulario de CHANGE
                if (isset($_GET['change']) && $_GET['change'] == "true") {

                        $values["telephonenumber"][0] = $_POST['telephonenumber'];
                        $values["ipphone"][0] = $_POST['ipphone'];

                        check_value($values["telephonenumber"][0], "Telefone");
                        check_value($values["ipphone"][0], "Ramal");

                        if ($_SESSION['dn'] == null) {
                                erro("Erro de sistema. DN nula.", "login.php");
                        }

                        if ($_SESSION['dn'] == "") {
                                erro("Erro de sistema. DN nula.", "login.php");
                        }

                        if (modify_user_attribute($_SESSION['dn'], $values)) {
                                include("_include/success.php");
                                return;
                        }else{
                                erro("Erro alterando atributos.", "modify.php");
                        }
                }
        }

}else{
        include("_include/modify.php");
        return;
}


?>
```

Here's how I'm thinking of using it to authenticate to more than one domain:

```
teste.php

<?php
$username = $_POST['username'];

$arr = explode("\\", $login);


echo "Dominio = " .strtoupper($arr[0]) ."\n";
echo "Login = $arr[1]\n";

$conf = array();

$conf["DOMAIN1"]["LDAP_SERVER"] = "iphost";
$conf["DOMAIN1"]["BIND_DN"] = "CN=LDAP Change Info,CN=Users,DC=domain1,DC=com,DC=br";
$conf["DOMAIN1"]["BIND_PWD"] = "passwordhere";
$conf["DOMAIN1"]["SEARCH_DN"] = "DC=domain1,DC=com,DC=br";


$conf["DOMAIN2"]["LDAP_SERVER"] = "iphost";
$conf["DOMAIN2"]["BIND_DN"] = "CN=LDAP Change Info,CN=Users,DC=domain2,DC=com,DC=br";
$conf["DOMAIN2"]["BIND_PWD"] = "passwordhere";
$conf["DOMAIN2"]["SEARCH_DN"] = "DC=domain2,DC=com,DC=br";


$conf["DOMAIN3"]["LDAP_SERVER"] = "iphost";
$conf["DOMAIN3"]["BIND_DN"] = "CN=LDAP Change Info,CN=Users,DC=domain3,DC=com,DC=br";
$conf["DOMAIN3"]["BIND_PWD"] = "passwordhere";
$conf["DOMAIN3"]["SEARCH_DN"] = "DC=domain3,DC=com,DC=br";

#var_dump($conf);


$dominio = strtoupper($arr[0]);

if ( empty($conf[$dominio]["LDAP_SERVER"])) {
die("Domain $dominio not found\n");

}

//echo "auth domain " .$conf[$dominio]["LDAP_SERVER"] ."\n";
```

I would like to know how it would be possible to join the raciocio line to be able to log in to other domains. 
I want to openly publish this code, it can help a lot of people.

Comment: You need a mapping of domains and return config by a single domain configuration. Hitting multiple DCs/domain is not common. And this one won't help people until you can create adapter library in packagist or package installable by composer or create a class. The current code is not testable and you should avoid global variables. Take a look at symfoy ldap component for example.

Comment: My intention is not to hit multiple domains simultaneously, but in fact it is to bind according to the domain that the user provides in the form, that is, to "knock" only in the domain informed only at a time. @Code_O1logn